# Does the "flower's name" myth have a real-world basis?

Tags: poyopoyo-kansatsu-nikki

In episode 6 of *Poyopoyo Kansatsu Nikki*, several stray kittens suddenly turn up at Moe's house, and her family nurses them until they can find a foster home. They also decide to give names to the kittens.

So, Moe suggests they name the kittens after flowers. Hide, her brother, replies that he thinks death comes sooner to those who have a flower's name.

[image: Hide: "But don't they say that you die earlier if you have a flower's name?"]

I've never heard this legend before; even Moe seems surprised (replying, "Do they?"). Is this based on a real legend (Japanese or otherwise), or is Hide misinformed?

Comment: I can't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the manga, Hide says:

[image: That's what he said!]

Which roughly translates to "but doesn't that sound a bit untimely?" Which probably refers to the fact that flowers lead short lives. Perhaps drawing indirectly from what Lord Capulet says in *Romeo and Juliet*?

> "Who said death lies on her like an untimely frost upon the sweetest flower of all the field?"

Luckily, the dad suggests: [image: Father has the best ideas]

"Fruit would be better." Perhaps referring to the kittens being young, while keeping with flower subject.